# Doxygen links to subroutines in other modules/files in Fortran

Tags: fortran, doxygen, doxywizard

I have a Fortran subroutine `proc` that calls Fortran subroutine `uv`. `uv` is in a different module with it's own module page in Doxygen.  I would like to add a link so that you can click on `uv` on the Doxygen page for `proc` and it will take you to the `uv` page.

I tried to do:

```
!> Comments
!! call \link uv \endlink

!> Comments
!! call \ref uv

!> Comments
!! call \see uv
```

None of these linked to the `uv` page.  Is there a better way to do it?  I used HTML links, and that worked, but that is cumbersome and will take a really long time because I have a lot of subroutines that are like this.

Comment: say your module has name tst, did you try tst::uv or tst.uv?

Comment: I tried tst::uv , tst:uv , and tst.uv
None of them seem to create a link to the other module page

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (current version is 1.8.11). Show some more code with attempts to create the link so it is possible to reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

With version 1.8.12, you can reference subroutines of other modules with `\ref module_name.subroutine_name` where `module_name` corresponds to the module name and `subroutine_name` corresponds to the subrotine name.

If this does not work, ensure that all your sources are declared in the `INPUT` variables of your `Doxyfile`.